# WCF -> Exe on IIS runs without purpose

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

My goal is to run a console application (.exe) from a WCF service on IIS.  It runs fine with Process.Start() to the executable directly from visual studio.  It also works from the command line.  But, it will not run the program through the service when hosted on IIS.

If I reduce the program to minimal function, it will return something.  Specifically when reduced to a single Console.WriteLine("test"), it will return "test".  Perhaps this implies it's not a permission issue?

When I debug the program it returns from the Process.Start() without creating the files it should, a message from standard output, and without any error.  I've wrapped the entire Main() of the executable in a try/catch and returned any exception to standard output, but still nothing from standard output.

I've read many possibilities, but none of them have helped.  I"m all out of ideas.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Happy to provide additional information.

Comment: i think for running your console application with minimum Console.WrtieLine it does not require any other helper class libraries, but in case of more line of code it would not be able to identify associated class libraries from the provide location.Have you set your references to copy local and tried this out using publishing or releasing your console application.

Comment: Are you sure IIS has the required privileges to start an application? also if its creating files IIS is going to need permission to write to that location, is there a reason it needs to be a console application? because if 1000 separate requests come in to your WCF service you are going to have a busy desktop with 1000 console windows :)